# How do I verify my self signed certificate

Tags: c#, security, cryptography, certificate

My web server is using a self-signed SSL certificate. I can connect to it by implementing the validation check myself:

```
private static Boolean ValidateCertificate(object sender,
     X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain,
     SslPolicyErrors sslpolicyerrors)
{
  return certificate.GetCertHashString().equals("ABCDEF");
}

private void Connect(String requestUrl)
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateCertificate;
    var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    //...
}
```

Is it secure to compare the hash returned by `GetCertHashString()` to a hard coded value to verify that this is really the certificate that is expected?

"Real" certificates are part of a chain, that has to be verified up to the root certificate, which is self signed. I'm guessing a verifiable part of that root certificate is hard coded into each application. This leads me to believe that my self signed certificate would be as secure as any other, as long as the hard coded values are not tampered with, which would mean access to the machine itself, in which case the standard root certificates could be tampered with too. Is that correct?

Comment: This question makes no sense.  All self-signed certificate is prove you are talking to yourself.  It is useless for anything on the public internet.

Comment: Why don't you just add your self signed certificate to the trusted certificates store?

Comment: @dtb: because I will need to support this app on .net4 under windows and mono under ubuntu and solaris. It just seems easier to do a simple check than going through all the hassle with the os'es.

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't understand your comment. I don't want to talk to myself, I want my client to talk to my server and be able to verify he gets the correct certificate, so that the communication is secure. Even if it where a paid certificate from Verisign, I would, at some point, need to verify the root certificate, which is itself self signed, so the problem stays the same.

Comment: The problem is: how do you get your self-signed certificate onto the machine of the client and how do you make sure that the certificate on the machine of the client is not tampered with?

Comment: Hard code it? If someone has access to the client machine and can alter my hard coded hash/cert he can most likely also add/remove any other cert from any other cert store, so...